# google app engine with mongodb and python

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, pymongo, google-app-engine-python

I'm using Python and MongoDB on google app engine but I cant find any reference on how to connect to MongoDB in development server that runs in a local machine with app engine.
Does anyone have a good reference on how to do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Which library do you use to connect to mongodb?

Comment: i m using pymongo for that

Comment: Try [this](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html). If you have deployed your mongodb on compute engine then the public ip of the instance can be used instead of localhost with the port on which your mongo is running. Not tested

Comment: i trying  to run the mongodb on local machine.

Comment: Could you site what error are you getting alongwith code snippet

Comment: Actually i don't know how can i achieve that. Is there any connector is available to use the mongodb stored in the local machine from the app engine. I m using eclipse for coding.

Comment: We can use mongodb with app engine in cloud, but i want to connect to the db that lies in my machine.

Comment: don't you just need to change the address of the server to localhost in that case ?